# read javascript file with PHP

Tags: php, file, input, readfile

please help me
I would like to read a javascript file and retrieve only lines starting with `url.instance = "www.google.fr";` in input 
in order to be able to modify these url

```
$handle = fopen('javascriptfile.js', 'r');
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        //echo $buffer."<br>";
        echo "<input type='text' value='$buffer'>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I have write this code but I don't know how to continue please help me

Comment: Could you make some examples what is inside of $buffer

Comment: `url.instance = "www.google.fr";` this string is frix?

Answer (score 0):

You can search each line with stripos

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('javascriptfile.js', 'r');
$match = 'url.instance = "www.google.fr";';

if ($handle) {

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);

        // check each line start with : url.instance = "www.google.fr";
        if (stripos($buffer, $match) === 0 ) {
            echo "<input type='text' value='$buffer'>";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```